# Font GDI Leaks with TextBox

Tags: c#

Found an issue in TextBox control in Win10 1809 or later versions of OS.
When I create a sample application as described in MSDN found that for every creation and dispose of TextBox control along with NativeWindow, There is an Font leaks.

MSDN link for sample : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.assignhandle?view=netframework-4.8

Just execute below sample code application will crash.

```
public partial class Form2 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddControlAndDispose(10000);
    }

    private void AddControlAndDispose(int cnt)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= cnt; i++)
        {
            var textBox = new CustomTextBox();
            Controls.Add(textBox);
            textBox.Dispose();
        }
    }
    private class CustomTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private NativeWindow m_TextBoxNativeWindow;
        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);
            if (m_TextBoxNativeWindow == null)
            {
                m_TextBoxNativeWindow = new NativeWindow();
            }
            m_TextBoxNativeWindow.AssignHandle(Handle);
        }

        protected override void OnHandleDestroyed(EventArgs e)
        {
            m_TextBoxNativeWindow?.ReleaseHandle();
            m_TextBoxNativeWindow = null;
            base.OnHandleDestroyed(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doe's it stil happen when you remove the created CustomTextBox() controls from the Controls collection?

Comment: yes, still the leaks will happen if remove the control also